# EF Core Lambda Expression Object Reference not set to an instance of an object on multiple joins

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am having weird error of `NullReferenceException` while querying the data using Entity framework core lambda syntax.

using this code

```
           var usersWithRights = await _dbContext.TblUsers.Where(x => x.IsInternal).Select(x => new
            {
                RightIds = x.TblInternalUserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.TblInternalRoleRights.Select(i => i.RightId).ToList()
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Where as the same code works when I apply `Count` instead of `Select` like

```
           var usersWithRights = await _dbContext.TblUsers.Where(x => x.IsInternal).Select(x => new
            {
                RightIds = x.TblInternalUserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.TblInternalRoleRights.Count
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Above code using `Count` give me the accurate result of count but I want to select the `RightIds`. I have crossed check that the record exists in my database and as a result when I query using `Count` it gives me the accurate result.

I just want to ask if there is any limit on Entity framework core while joining data? like are there a maximum number of joins allowed in EF Core or I can join any number of tables?

Comment: There are no limits, but the same cannot be said for bugs. What EF Core version is this?

Comment: EF Core 3.1, by the way I have found out a hack to do the same, I have included All three tables first and loaded all the data in memory using `var usersWithRights = await _dbContext.TblUsers.Include(x => x.TblInternalUserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role).ThenInclude(x => x.TblInternalRoleRights).Where(x => x.IsInternal).ToListAsync();` and then I was able to get the RightIds. It found out to be something related to lazy loading as EF was not loading all the navigation properties automatically so I had to forcefully include that. Also I was not able to select any properties in that statement

Comment: Hmm, projection (`Select`) queries normally don't need `Include` / `ThenInclude` (nor lazy loading). Except if EFC tries to use client evaluation. `FirstOrDefault()` looks suspicious and most likely is causing the issue. Why do you need it? How about replacing it with `SelectMany`, e.g.  `RightIds = x.TblInternalUserRoles.SelectMany(ur => ur.Role.TblInternalRoleRights.Select(i => i.RightId)).ToList()`

Comment: Thankyou so much for this wonderful answer, I had no idea about SelectMany, Its working perfectly. Please post this as an answer so that I can happily accept and Upvote :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no join limits, but unfortunately there are still many shortcomings/bugs/issues with EF Core query translation of some LINQ constructs.

Normally you don't need `Include` / `ThenInclude` in projection (`Select`) queries because they are ignored. But getting NRE w/o them here indicates client evaluation attempt (EF Core 3.x still sypports client evaluation for some constructs, and mainly in final projection like here), which in turn means failed translation.

Here the problem seems to be

```
x.TblInternalUserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.TblInternalRoleRights.Select(i => i.RightId)
```

i.e. converting sequence (`x.TblInternalUserRoles`) to single element (`.FirstOrDefault()`) and then taking subsequence (`.Role.TblInternalRoleRights`).

The working solution is to use `SelectMany` operator for flattening the source sequence. `FirstOrDefault()` should be removed (it makes no sense to me) or if really needed, replaced with the corresponding equivalent sequence operator `Take(1)`.

e.g.

```
RightIds = x.TblInternalUserRoles
    .SelectMany(ur => ur.Role.TblInternalRoleRights.Select(i => i.RightId))
    .ToList()
```

or

```
RightIds = x.TblInternalUserRoles
    .SelectMany(ur => ur.Role.TblInternalRoleRights, (ur, i) => i.RightId)
    .ToList()
```

or

```
RightIds = x.TblInternalUserRoles
    .SelectMany(ur => ur.Role.TblInternalRoleRights)
    .Select(i => i.RightId)
    .ToList()
```

Comment: That was what exactly needed!